# PHP lockout user after 3 failed log ins for 10 minutes

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication, limit

I have the code for a log in system almost done. I have it working that a user gets 3 attempts to login and receive a message each time saying that they have a certain number of attempts left.                                                                                  I also have coded for if they have been logged in for 5 minutes they will automatically be logged out.                                                                                   I am struggling on how to lock the user out for 10 minutes based on session variables. Could anyone tell me where to set the session variable ['LoginID'] and what conditions it needs to be in because at the moment, I am getting an error that it is an undefined variable. If someone could help me with my current code instead of providing a different method altogether, that would be great because then, I could actually understand it. Here is my code:

```
//careMarkBase starts a session, connects to the DB and has the following code for logging out a user after 5 minutes(which works)
$duration = (5 * 60);
if(isset($_SESSION['started'])){

    $time = ($duration - (time() - $_SESSION['started']));

    if($time <= 0){

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();          
    }
}
else{

  $_SESSION['started'] = time();
}
```

and this is the login php

```
<?php include "CareMarkBase.php"; ?>  
    <?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
        {
            echo "<p>Thanks for logging in <b>".$_SESSION['FName']." ".$_SESSION['SName']."</b>.</p>";
            echo "<a href='CareMarkLogout.php'><input name='logoutBtn' type='submit' value='Logout'/></a>";
            #set failed_login_attempts = 0
            $set_failed_login_attempts=mysql_query("UPDATE login SET failed_login_attempts=0 WHERE LoginID=".$_SESSION['LoginID']);

        }
        elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $userID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

            $checkloginEmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserDetails WHERE UserID = '".$userID."' AND Password = '".$password."'") or die(mysql_error());

            if(mysql_num_rows($checkloginEmp) == 1)
            {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($checkloginEmp);
                $_SESSION['Username'] = $userID;
                $_SESSION['FName'] = $row['FName'];
                $_SESSION['SName'] = $row['SName'];
                $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;


                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;CareMarkLogin2.php'/>";
            }
            else
            {
                if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedAttempts'])){
                    $_SESSION['LoggedAttempts']++;
                }
                else{
                    $_SESSION['LoggedAttempts'] = 0;
                }

                $login = mysql_query("SELECT failed_login_attempts, last_failed_login FROM login WHERE LoginID ='".$_SESSION['LoginID']."'")or die(mysql_error()); 

                if(mysql_num_rows($login) == 0){

                    #create failed_login_attempts = failed_login_attempts + 1 AND last_failed_login = NOW()
                    $failed_login_attempts=mysql_query("INSERT INTO login VALUES ('','".$_SESSION['LoggedAttempts']."',NOW())");
                }

                else{
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($login);
                    $_SESSION['LoginID'] = $row['LoginID'];
                    $update_failed_login_attempts=mysql_query("UPDATE login SET failed_login_attempts='".$_SESSION['LoggedAttempts']."', 
                    last_failed_login = NOW() WHERE LoginID ='".$_SESSION['LoginID']."'") or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }


                $login_attempts_remaining=2 - $_SESSION['LoggedAttempts'];

                if ($login_attempts_remaining<=0){
                    echo 'Locked out!';
                    //going to add code here after to check if they were locked out for more than 10 minutes then to set failed login attempts back to zero
                }
                else{

                echo "Login Details Incorrect<p></p><p></p>";
                echo "<p>Please try again or contact head office on 091 771705</p>
                      <p>You have ". $login_attempts_remaining ." login attempts remaining. </p>
                      <p> <form action='CareMarkLogin2.php' method='POST'>
                            <input type='submit' name='login' id='login' value='Try again'/>
                          </form>
                      </p>";
                }
        }
        //}

    else{

        ?>  
        <div id="mainText" style="width:400px;text-align:center;float:left" class="post">
            <form method="post" action="CareMarkLogin2.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br/><br/>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

After verifying the account information, check if they should be locked out.

```
        if(mysql_num_rows($checkloginEmp) == 1)
        {
            // Check if they're locked out
            $checkLockout = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login
                                         WHERE LoginID = $userID
                                         AND failed_login_attempts >= 3
                                         AND last_failed_login > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)" or die (mysql_error());
            if (mysql_num_rows($checkLockout) > 0) {
                echo "Locked out!";
            } else {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($checkloginEmp);
                $_SESSION['Username'] = $userID;
                $_SESSION['FName'] = $row['FName'];
                $_SESSION['SName'] = $row['SName'];
                $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
            }

            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;CareMarkLogin2.php'/>";
        }
```

Alternatively, you could check this before validating the password.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I'm a bit confused. The loginID isn't equal to the user ID though.The main problem I had was what to set $_SESSION['LoginID'] to and where...

Comment: Why are you using different IDs? If they're not yet logged in, the only ID you have to work with is the username, and that's what the timeout should be associated with.

Comment: I changed the layout because I was getting too confused but thanks!