# Why not use sessions instead of a database for account lockout

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication, brute-force

I'm building a web applicaton and was researching about account lockout as a way to tackle bruteforce attacks. Looking for the best way to implement this brought me to the following links

[1. limited attempts for login and block a users account for a specific amout of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191685/limited-attempts-for-login-and-block-a-users-account-for-a-specific-amout-of-tim)

[2. PHP lockout user after 3 failed log ins for 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509643/php-lockout-user-after-3-failed-log-ins-for-10-minutes)

[3. Blocking access to the login page after three unsuccessful login attempts](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/blocking_system_access.php)

[4. How to block user after 3 fail of submiting wrong information](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/288929-php-how-to-block-user-after-3-fail-of-submiting-wrong-information/)

There's many more links, but they all said the same thing:

```
1. Create Database
2. Store Login Attempt Details
3. Add 1 to number of attempts
4. Set timed session if No of attempts > 3/5
```

This however got me thinking, why isnt the below method better or atleast equally good?

```
1. Set a session "[No of login attempts]" on failed login
2. Add "1" to "[No of login attempts]" on each failed login
3. Proceed with account lockout if "Session[No of login attempts]" is greater than 3/5
```

I got a feeling this is better because of it's simlicity. The database method adds to unnecessary overhead, and tasks with managing the table.(one might want to delete failed login details from the past or on login resolution etc)

But I don't see anyone recommending this method

What am I missing here?

Comment: A CAPTCHA  protects from bruit force

Comment: sessions are obviously a bad idea because any bot will just clear them on every attempt

Comment: And bots can attack from several computers at once.

Comment: Things i was not aware of, @Dagon , I'm aware of CAPTCHA, but my organisation policy needs account lockout as well

Comment: well simply sessions wont work, you have to store the data locally, so a database makes most sense - if inserting a single row into your database is causing to much 'overhead' you got other problems

Comment: I always thought Session were in the control only from the server side (Thus making them as secure as a DB) I also thought they are linked to cookies, which you say isn't true. In this case what is it about sessions that don't make them safe

Comment: session content is stored on the server, but the client has to send something to match that content to that request, a cookie is one way, the url is another. A bot\client could choose\be told to not send that session id, so every visit looks brand new to your application

Comment: Thanks @Dagon, had no idea about the URL aspect with sessions. Had you made this an answer would have accepted it. Nevertheless, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Sessions time out.  If your attacker just waits long enough, the count of their failures will be forgotten.
2. Sessions can be tied to cookies.  In this case, if the attacker clears their cookies, they will get a new session ID and a new set of counters.  If the attacker figures out your cookie scheme, they can even create their own cookies and get as many sessions as they want.
3. Sessions can also be tracked by parameters on URLs.  In this case, retrying with the base URL will reset the login attempts.  Also, as with the cookies, if the attacker can figure out your session ID scheme, then can then generate a large number of them.

Comment: "Sessions are tied to cookies" nope

Comment: PHP sessions create a cookie with the key `PHPSESSID`, they DO use cookies.

Comment: they CAN use cookies, session ids can also propagate via the url

Comment: @Dagon this is interesting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies but seems that using sessions in the URL is the _only_ alternative to cookies, but rightly highly discouraged.

Comment: the question is about bruit force, your answers imply a human agent